# Max and min number of keys in a B-tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, b-tree

What is the maximum and minimum number of keys that can be stored in a B-tree of order 128 and height 3?

For the maximum, here's what I did:
You have a single root node. The maximum children a root node can have is m (order), so that's 128. And each of those 128 children have 128 children, so that gives us a total of 1+128+16384=16512 total nodes. According to Wikipedia, a B-tree of n nodes can store n-1 keys, so that leaves us with a maximum of 16511 keys.

For min:
You have a single root node, and the minimum number of children this can have is 2, and the minimum number of children these 2 children can have are m/2, where m is the order, so 64 children each. That leaves us with 1+2+64+64=131 total children and 131-1=130 keys.

Is what I have done here correct?

Comment: This is completely wrong calculation and the accepted answer also guides in false direction. The question is about min and max no. of keys but you are counting nodes of B-tree and then calculating min/max no. of keys that can be stored in a node with x children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you define order. According to Knuth, the order of a b-tree is the maximum number of children, which would mean that the max answer is 129. If the definition of order is the minimum number of keys of a non-root node, then the answer to the max is unknown.

Using [this](http://cis.stvincent.edu/carlsond/swdesign/btree/btree.html) definition, your calculation of minimum is correct, but your maximum is not, because *every* node, including the leaves, contains m-1 keys. This is also consistent with the definition of B-Tree in Cormen. if n is 16512, and each n stores 127 keys, the answer is definitely not 16511.

Answer (score 6):

according to wikipedia , a node can have at most n-1 keys if it has n child nodes.
therefore ,

```
                           root [127keys]
                 128 childnodes [each having 127 keys]
             128*128 childnodes [each having 127 keys]

127+128*127+128*128*127 = total no of maximum allowed keys
```

Comment: Isn't this only a tree of height 2? I see a tree of height 0 as one node (the root).

Answer (score 6):

There are lower and upper bounds on the number of keys a node can contain. These bounds are expressed in terms of a fixed integer t >= 2 called the minimum degree of the B-tree.

- Every node other than the root must have at least t - 1 keys.
  Every internal node other than the root has at least t children.
  If the tree is nonempty, the root must have at least one key.
- Every node can contain at most 2t - 1 keys.
  Therefore, an internal node can have at most 2t children.
  We say that a node is full if it contains exactly 2t - 1 keys.

Max no of keys for height 3 = (2t-1) + (2t-1) * 2t + (2t-1) * 2t * 2t
Min no of keys for height 3 = (t-1) + (t-1)*t + (t-1) * t * t

Comment: isn't this possible to express as a formula with h = heigth and t = degree of the b-tree:

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C# code to compute maximum number of keys for any B-Tree given number of levels and maximum number of children a node can have.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Given number of levels in the tree, computes the maximum number of keys the tree can hold. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="levelCount">Is the number of levels in the tree. </param>
        /// <param name="MaxBranchingDegree ">Is the maximum number of children a node in the tree can have. </param>
        /// <returns>Maximum number of keys a tree with <paramref name="levelCount"> levels can hold. </returns>
        public int ComputeMaxKeyCount(int levelCount, int MaxBranchingDegree )
        {
           int maxKeys = 0;
           for (int l = 0; l < levelCount; l++)
           {
              maxKeys += (MaxBranchingDegree - 1) * (int)Math.Pow(MaxBranchingDegree, l);
           }
           return maxKeys;
        }
```